# Audio from Edge started to stutter when Edge runs in background

Tags: audio, browser, background-process

I have been listening to music through a web application in Edge for over a year. A few days ago, sporadically the sound has become stuttery. I noticed that this is happening when Edge is explicitly going into background mode. When I show the recent apps, there is a link named "1 active in background".

[image]

When I tap the link, an option appears to stop Edge.

[image]

As soon as I open Edge normally, the stutter disappears, so the sound turns normal.

How can I stop the stuttering? Or is there a possibility to tell Edge not to go in background mode?

This happens on Samsung Galaxy S21, Android 13, Edge 108.0 . Sound output was any time over bluetooth.